# How values from TextArea can be saved in database from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I can pass values from textbox to my database this way,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox3.Text.ToString());
```

But I am not able to pass values from textarea to my database this way,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDRESS", TextArea1.Text.ToString());
```

The text area is defined like so:

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" name="S1" rows="2"></textarea>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @ Kiran Hegde, yup! it shows:
Error 5 The name 'TextArea1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Can you show us the html code please? Is `TextArea1` a type of TextBox?

Comment: @ Schadensbegrenzer: here it is     <textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" name="S1" rows="2"></textarea>

Comment: there should not be any problem..just check your length of address field in your database...

Comment: @Mimi, Is there any issue with using the <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2"></asp:TextBox> ? OR you just want to use html tags and not the asp.net controls ?

Comment: have you tried debugging with a breakpoint on that line and checking your local variables or using the immediate window to interrogate the controls on the page?

Comment: You are just missing runat="server", this is required since you want to access the control in codebehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a server element in order to be able to access it in your c# code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextArea1" TextMode="Multiline" Columns="20" Name="S1" Rows="2"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: @Mimi: was this answer helpful to you? If not, how can I help more?

Comment: After adding runat="server" it shows another error, Error 5 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My answer goes further then just adding the runat tag. Can you try my code and post the error message?

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman: oh thanks a lot. it works. but i've a qs is it not possible to use asp textarea in stead of textbox?

Comment: @Mimi: it doesn't exist. This code will generate a `textarea`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ADDRESS", SqlType.VarChar).Value = TextArea1.Text.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use :`<textarea runat="server" id="TextArea1" cols="20" name="S1" rows="2"></textarea>`

in source

and code behind use the "`TextArea1.InnerText`" you will not get that error which states `After adding runat="server" it shows another error, Error 5   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`